# Using smaller than operator in AWS Athena does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have ran into an issue with filtering timestamps in AWS Athena. I am using Athena to query parquet-files in S3. I have ran a crawler to include the schema of the files into AWSDataCatalogue. Everything is working fine unless I try to use the smaller than operator and I have no explanation why this is happening. I try to filter for a specific daterange with >= and <=. I have tried the examples below and was able to identify the smaller than-operator as the cause for the issue.
Here is an example, my goal is to filter for specific dates:

```
select col_1, col_2, ts_col 
from "database"."table" 
where ts_col >= date('2021-04-26') and ts_col <= date('2021-04-26');
```

This is the query that I am trying to run, but it returns "Zero Records" and "Data Scanned: 0.0 KB".

The query

```
select col_1, col_2, ts_col 
from "database"."table" 
where ts_col <= date('2021-04-26');
```

returns the desired output (all data after 2021-04-25).

But if I try this:

```
select col_1, col_2, ts_col 
from "database"."table" 
where ts_col <= date('2021-04-26');
```

the query does not return anything ("Zero records"), even if there are records before this date in the DB. It looks like there isn't even data scanned during query execution ("Data Scanned: 0.0 KB").

I already tried another syntax for the daterange query with

```
select col_1, col_2, ts_col 
from "database"."table" 
where ts_col between date('2021-04-26') and date('2021-04-26');
```

as well as

```
select col_1, col_2, ts_col 
from "database"."table" 
where ts_col between timestamp '2021-04-26 00:00:00.000' 
and timestamp '2021-04-26 23:59:99.999';
```

but no query has returned anything else than "Zero Records" yet with "Data Scanned: 0.0 KB".

I checked the data type of the `ts_col` in the AWSDataCatalogue and it is registered as `timestamp`.

Has anyone encountered this issue yet or am I making an obvious mistake?

Comment: Did you try simply `=`? If you only want that day data. You can also try to use `date(ts_col)` or `date_trunc('day', ts_col)` to make sure that you are comparing the same types.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! Looks like the problem was indeed caused by different data types. If I use ```date(ts_col)``` the query returns the desired output. Interesting that the query above with the ```timestamp``` does not work, it should be the same data type.
Thanks for your help!